# In nodejs how to send cookies in a request to a server

Tags: node.js, cookies, request, response, setcookie

how can we receive a cookie as the 'set-cookie' parameter of the response and header and then send this cookie in next request.All this using the 'http' module and no 3rd party modules.I am basically interested on how i will post the cookie as a parameter in the header about to go in the next request

Comment: What have you tried so far, however incomplete? Are you trying to parse an [`IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) from a browser or make a [`ClientRequest`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) from Node to another server?

Answer (score 7):

oh finally found my mistake i wasnt including the cookie parameter in my header list.I was writing it like this:

```
var options = {host:url_parsed.host, path:url_parsed.path, method:'GET', 'Cookie':cookie, 'Accept':'/', 'Connection':'keep-alive', };
```

I should actually be like this:

```
 var options = {host:url_parsed.host, path:url_parsed.path, method:'GET', headers:{'Cookie':cookie}, 'Accept':'/', 'Connection':'keep-alive', };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a cookie in the header like this:

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=testvalue',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
});
response.end('Hello World\n');
```

Comment: prekolna what i am taking about is a client request.Have to set the cookie in the request from the client.

Comment: got the answer but since i am a new user i can put it up here.

Comment: oh finally found my mistake 

i wasnt including the cookie parameter in my header list.I was writing it like this:

Comment: var options = {host:url_parsed.host,
      path:url_parsed.path,
     method:'GET',
     'Cookie':cookie,
     'Accept':'*/*',
     'Connection':'keep-alive',
 };

Comment: I should actually be like this:

    var options = {host:url_parsed.host,
      path:url_parsed.path,
     method:'GET',
     headers:{'Cookie':cookie},
     'Accept':'*/*',
     'Connection':'keep-alive',
 };

Thanks to all those who commented.I guess this solves the problem